# New column with value of last string with a sign in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr, tidy

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
    example2
# A tibble: 11 x 2
   municipality_name                            municipality_code
   <chr>                                        <chr>            
 1 - Zürich                                     ZH               
 2 >> Bezirk Affoltern                          000101           
 3 ......Aeugst am Albis                        0001             
 4 ......Affoltern am Albis                     0002             
 5 ......Bonstetten                             0003             
 6 - Bern / Berne                               BE               
 7 >> Arrondissement administratif Jura bernois 000241           
 8 ......Corgémont                              0431             
 9 ......Cormoret                               0432             
10 ......Cortébert                              0433             
11 ......Courtelary                             0434
```

What I want to do is to create four new columns:
i. One (`canton`) which is the last row that starts with "- " for each row,
ii. another (`bezirk`) that is the last row starting with ">> " and
iii. iv. two more(`canton_code` and `bezirk_code`)  with their values of `municipality_code`.

So basically, this:

```
ideal
# A tibble: 11 x 6
   municipality_name                            municipality_code canton            bezirk                                       canton_code bezirk_code
   <chr>                                        <chr>             <chr>             <chr>                                        <chr>       <chr>      
 1 - Zürich                                     ZH                "- Zürich"        >> Bezirk Affoltern                          ZH          000101     
 2 >> Bezirk Affoltern                          000101            "- Zürich"        >> Bezirk Affoltern                          ZH          000101     
 3 ......Aeugst am Albis                        0001              "- Zürich"        >> Bezirk Affoltern                          ZH          000101     
 4 ......Affoltern am Albis                     0002              "- Zürich"        >> Bezirk Affoltern                          ZH          000101     
 5 ......Bonstetten                             0003              "- Bern / Berne " >> Arrondissement administratif Jura bernois BE          000241     
 6 - Bern / Berne                               BE                "- Bern / Berne " >> Arrondissement administratif Jura bernois BE          000241     
 7 >> Arrondissement administratif Jura bernois 000241            "- Bern / Berne " >> Arrondissement administratif Jura bernois BE          000241     
 8 ......Corgémont                              0431              "- Bern / Berne " >> Arrondissement administratif Jura bernois BE          000241     
 9 ......Cormoret                               0432              "- Bern / Berne " >> Arrondissement administratif Jura bernois BE          000241     
10 ......Cortébert                              0433              "- Bern / Berne " >> Arrondissement administratif Jura bernois BE          000241     
11 ......Courtelary                             0434              "- Bern / Berne " >> Arrondissement administratif Jura bernois BE          000241
```

I am really struggling with this and I'm sure there must be an easier way to get at it so I'm hoping someone here know how to get this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you `dput` your data?

Comment: ofc! here: 
dput(example2)
structure(list(ID = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 
185L, 186L), municipality_name = c("- Zürich", ">> Bezirk Affoltern", 
"......Aeugst am Albis", "......Affoltern am Albis", "......Bonstetten", 
"- Bern / Berne", ">> Arrondissement administratif Jura bernois", 
"......Corgémont", "......Cormoret", "......Cortébert", "......Courtelary"
), municipality_code = c("ZH", "000101", "0001", "0002", "0003", 
"BE", "000241", "0431", "0432", "0433", "0434")), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that is to search for the required delimiter and create a column with it, then filling the empty values with the last non-null value.

Below is an example of how you can do that;

```
# Loading required libraries
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

# Creating sample data
example <- read.table(text ='
- Zürich|ZH 
>> Bezirk Affoltern|000101 
......Aeugst am Albis|0001 
......Affoltern am Albis|0002 
......Bonstetten|0003 
- Bern / Berne|BE 
>> Arrondissement administratif Jura bernois|000241 
......Corgémont|0431 
......Cormoret|0432 
......Cortébert|0433 
......Courtelary|0434',header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = "|", 
                      col.names = c("municipality_name", "municipality_code"))

example %>%
  # If column starts with required delimiter then include the required column else null
  mutate(canton = ifelse(str_starts(municipality_name, "-"), municipality_name, NA_character_),
         bezirk = ifelse(str_starts(municipality_name, ">>"), municipality_name, NA_character_),
         canton_code = ifelse(str_starts(municipality_name, "-"), municipality_code, NA_character_),
         bezirk_code = ifelse(str_starts(municipality_name, ">>"), municipality_code, NA_character_)) %>%
  # Use tidyr fill function to fill value with last non null value
  fill(all_of(c("canton", "bezirk", "canton_code", "bezirk_code")), .direction = "down")
```

Comment: brilliant. That's an easier (and smarter) way of doing it compared to everything I've tried. thank you so much!